# Tokens for several resources in ADFS

Tags: angular, single-page-application, openid-connect, adfs

I have ADFS 4.0
I have setup Web API resource and get access tokend for this resource using `resource` parameter.
I have SPA angluar app that logins and gets token
I receive audience like this: `microsoft:identityserver:web.API` and it is correct and expectable.

So question:
What is the best practice to handle situation when i have several APIs within one Application group on ADFS?

Should I create 2 threads refreshing tokens for two APIs for example? or is there a way to request one token for two APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would aim to develop things in line with industry OAuth standards, which are based on scopes and claims, as in the below articles. This will give you the best future options for authorization and also for porting your code, eg to Azure AD:

- [Scope Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/)
- [Claims Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/)

It is standard for an OAuth client such as an SPA to get one type of token, with particular scopes and claims, and for that token to be forwarded to multiple APIs in a microservices architecture. This also leads to simple code.

Each related set of APIs will receive an access token with values such as these, and each API should then validate the token in terms of its expected audience and scopes, then use claims for finer grained authorization:

- audience: 'api.mycompany.com'
- scope: 'inventory_read orders_write'

It is not standard to register a separate OAuth client for each API and one option might be to register a 'default' logical resource to represent your API platform. In ADFS you may then be able to model scopes similar to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-v1-app-scopes):

```cs
string ResourceId = "https://api.mycompany.com/";
var scopes = new [] { ResourceId + "inventory_read", ResourceID + "orders_write"}
```

It's been a while since I used ADFS and you may need to adapt things based on its limitations - but hopefully this helps to clarify your requirements a little.

Note also that a 'resource' parameter used to be required when getting access tokens in Azure AD 1.0 but has been replaced by scopes in Azure AD 2.0.